# PHP defining document root on badly configured shared server

Tags: php

I have an account on a shared server which is no longer maintained and isn't very well configured.

```
echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] = '/path/to/my/root/and/now/path/to/my/file/location.php'
```

but ...

```
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = '/var/www'
```

I needed to find the site root so I wrote my own method to do so. What I am wondering is if anyone sees a reason why this wouldn't work consistently before I put it into production?

Note: I know that it won't work with includes/requires, url-rewriting or with index.php or any other root extensions apache is configured to access silently.

Here's my method:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', str_replace(str_replace('/'.basename(__FILE__),'',     
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_URL"]),'',dirname(__FILE__)));

require_once ROOT_PATH.'/and/now/path/to/my/file/location.php';
```

In essence, it removes the script name from the script url, then removes any directory names found after the root.

EDIT: My description above said 'after the root' but the str_replace did not care where in the string that the replacement took place. This could have broken it. Therefore I have revised my solution to only replace the last instance of the matching paths:

```
define('ROOT_PATH',preg_replace('(.*)'.
preg_quote(str_replace('/'.basename(__FILE__),'',
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_URL"]),'~').'(.*?)~','$1'.''.'$2',dirname(__FILE__),1));
```

`preg_replace` is a little slower unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure it is not related to symlinks, do `realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])` and `realpath(ROOT_PATH)` give two different paths?

Comment: the former gives me `/var/www`, the latter gives the result I want from my function @jeroen.

Comment: is moving to a maintained server or your own VPS not an option? if this is an indication, you might end up with all sorts of other issues on this server

Comment: Agreed @HorusKol, it's the next step, but the code must work on this server and the new one unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to just avoid using that at all, and define an 'application root' instead. If your `index.php` is in this file, you should just :

```
define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

If you want to define this in some included file instead, for example `includes/approot.php`, just call `dirname` again for every subfolder :

```
define('APP_ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Knowing the document root isn't that useful. Knowing the application root is.

Comment: So, if I want to use this in a folder here: `very/deep/path/to/my/folder/` I'd do `dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))))`. My method eliminates the need to have to think about what directory level I am in for every script. The same code works for all levels.

Comment: @user2320402 You only need to execute my code in one file that can just sit in the root of the application, whereas your code relies on `SCRIPT_URL` which should only be used in the first file called by Apache.

Comment: What happens if the visitor first enters the website at a page that isn't in the root and can't be redirected?

Comment: @user2320402 Then that probably wasn't really the root of your application.